# removing lines by sed

Tags: command-line, sed

I have text inside some lines which is inside at below, and to extract Some lines using that command;

```
cat meyveler.txt

elma armut ve ayva daha cok kış meyveleridir
ancak,
yaz mevyeleride oldukca lezzetli oldugu gözden kacmamalıdır.
ayrıca tüm bunlara istinaden tüm calısmalat gözden gecirilebilir olmalıdır.
12.ayın gelmesiyle beraber ayva ve Nar sezonu hareketlenmeye,
Bus senenin bitisiylede Hamsiler hareketlenmeye baslayacaktır.
=tabi bu işlemler bu sekilde akıp gider
```

And to extract some lines using that command;

```
cat meyveler.txt | egrep "^[^a-z].*$"

12.ayın gelmesiyle beraber ayva ve Nar sezonu hareketlenmeye,
Bus senenin bitisiylede Hamsiler hareketlenmeye baslayacaktır.
=tabi bu işlemler bu sekilde akıp gider
```

Now i try to delete this line by this but i m getting error, what should i use for that?

```
cat meyveler.txt | egrep "^[^a-z].*$" | xargs -Iline sed -i "/line/d"
```

Comment: So you want to delete every line from a text file that does not start with a latin lowercase letter a-z?

Comment: actually this is test working , i d like  exactly what i did

Comment: Sorry, what? I did not understand your last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is:

```
grep '^[a-z]' meyveler.txt
```

Which only returns the lines matched with your desired pattern, there is no need to use `cat`, `egrep`, `xargs` or `sed`.

---

**Explanation of error:**

You don't have any file to process using `sed` so you can't use `-i`.

- `-i` edits the files in their place

Actually you are piping your file `meyveler.txt` contents as a stream to the `sed` command, and `sed` will edit it in the stdout.

- Note that your `cat` command is unnecessary, `xargs` too.

However as steeldriver mentioned that, you are looking for:

```
egrep "^[^a-z].*$" meyveler.txt | xargs -Iline sed -i "/line/d" meyveler.txt
```

Comment: no i have file called meyveler.txt

Comment: But you are not passing the file to the `sed` you are piping its content to the `sed` that's the different.

Comment: when i perform your command, not able to delete lines, did i do something wrong?

Comment: @Ravexina the OP is piping the *pattern* to `sed` presumably in order to edit the same file from which the pattern was grepped; what's missing is the filename at the end of it all i.e. `egrep "^[^a-z].*$" meyveler.txt | xargs -Iline sed -i  "/line/d" meyveler.txt`. But only in a code-obfuscation contest.

Comment: @solfish check the update ;)

Comment: yes exactly correct!!

Comment: @solfish check my alternative solution too ;)

Comment: @Ravexina thanks for your cautions, i m trying to learn some other ways, thanks for solution again

Comment: Your last command (the one redirecting output to `new.meyveler.txt`) does not work, because `sed` has no input data to work with, just like in the failed approach in the question.

Comment: @ByteCommander didn't pay attention, you're right... removed and thanks ;)

Comment: how did you do that @Ravexina:)), made me suprised

Comment: @solfish I didn't get much sleep these days :D

Answer (score 3):

Given a file `meyveler.txt`, you can delete all lines that start *not* with a lowercase letter `a-z` with `sed` simply like this:

```
sed '/^[^a-z]/d' meyveler.txt
```

The above command will read from your file and print the filtered output to the terminal. If you want to edit the file directly in-place, add the `-i` flag. You can preserve the original file as backup if you specify a suffix (e.g. `-i.bak` will keep the original data as `meyveler.txt.bak`):

```
sed -i '/^[^a-z]/d' meyveler.txt
```

You don't need `cat` to read the file and you don't need `grep` or `egrep` to filter them. All this functionality is built into `sed`.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding at above comment i mean that there are several ways to do but i m trying to progress other combination ways. thanks @Byte Commander

Comment: Aha. But your approach is so overcomplicated. First, why do you want to use `cat` to read the file? Every tool in your command-line can read directly from files, you don't need another one for that task. Second, if you combine `grep` and `sed` with `xargs`, every output line from `grep` i.e. every line you want to delete causes a separate invocation of `sed` which processes the whole file every time just to delete every line that contains the string `grep` outputted. In other words, you search the whole file numerous times instead of once and you might even end up with too many deletions.

Comment: hımm, i see you now clearly